# Добавление в StringBuilder символа char

Tags: java

мне необходимо получить случайный символ из двух вариантов (0 или 1). Сделал я это путем получение рандомного инта (48 или 49), т.к. по таблице эти символы соответствуют нулю и единице. Далее мне нужно в StringBuilder добавить полученный символ, и тут я запутался как это сделать... да, есть insert, но как туда добавить char элемент полученный числом? Покажу как это выглядит на коде.

```
public StringBuilder randomMagnet() {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        int number = 48 + random.nextInt(49 - 48 + 1);

        temp.insert(0, number); //тут естественно в темп добавится 48 или 49
        return temp;
    }
```

Можно конечно получить случайный символ другим способом, например создать массив char, и получать из него случайный элемент, но мой способ мне сначала показался быстрее и короче, но потом зашел в тупик, а можно ли выйти из него стало очень интересно, может я не вижу очевидного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явно скастуйте число в char `(char) number`. Тогда будет использоваться другой метод `insert`. Не `insert(int, int)`, а `insert(int, char)`